How it is possible to be both "libertaire" and "center-left"?
The term "libertaire" is a quite ambiguous French political term.
The definition is "Which, in theory as in practice, goes as far as possible in the direction of absolute individual freedom; which is inspired by or which claims to be an ideal or a doctrine of absolute freedom." (CNRTL, checked Google translate)
It seems like a term referring to the theory and movement of left-anarchism:

The term libertaire designates people, currents, movements, structures and organizations which advocate individual freedom as a fundamental value, and which therefore reject any form of political authoritarianism in social organization1 or private life. Libertaire is more particularly a synonym for anarchist, used to refer to this current of political philosophy developed since the 19th century on a set of anti-authoritarian and self-management theories and practices, based on direct democracy.
[Wikipedia, checked Google translate.]

Philippe Val, a French journalist, once director of Charlie Hebdo, describes himself as both a "libertaire" and a "center-left".

I always felt a little libertaire all that, but, center-left, when I went to vote you see what I mean"
(original: "je me suis toujours senti un peu libertaire tout ça, mais, centre-gauche, quand j'allais voter quoi"; Philippe Val, C à vous, 2022, 4:35).

Center-left is normally associated with social-democracy or social-liberalism, that is, theories where a state redistributes wealth. The existence of a state enters in contradiction with the libertaire principle of "absolute freedom" (such a state will be in charge of economic regulation, police, execution of laws, etc.).
How it is possible to be both "libertaire" and "center-left"?

Meh, it's not like there are many anarchist parties that have real power in France. This is more like a pragmatic choice to vote for something rather than stay home and dream of some utopia. FWTW https://libcom.org/library/vive-lanarchie-interview-french-anarchists

You might want to read up on the political compass and the orthogonal relationship between economics and social liberalism. Pretty much all societies require some taxation, and no society allows absolute freedom - even classical American right-libertarianism accepts that my freedom ends at your nose (or your property). In contrast things like having enough to eat and having healthcare allow people to pursue many freedoms. I'm sure this is a duplicate though.

Compare Is an Anarchosocialist a valid political term?, Is Communism intrinsically authoritarian?, Is Libertarianism left wing or right wing? etc

@StuartF Thank you for your comments which are very useful. I suspect though that there is a confusion in the terms. In France the term "libertaire" is not a translation for the English "libertarian". The term "libertaire" is very linked to the left, and means, at least in my knowledge "left-wing anarchism". Taking the political compass I would then place "libertaire" at the bottom left corner of the square. On the other hand, center-left would be on the middle line, in the middle of the left part of this line. Therefore the incompatibility that I see here.

"quite ambiguous" applies to all political classification, which is a strong statement.

If your translated quote is accurate he says he "felt a little libertaire" (emph mine). Feeling "a little" drawn to an ideology isn't the same as being fully committed to it, so it specifically implies that he doesn't hold absolutely to libertaire values. So a zero-research reading of just the material you've presented here suggests that Philippe Val is claiming that he thinks individual freedom is important, and also that centre-left principles are important. That sounds to me like a fairly ordinary position, not one with surprising contradictions that need explaining.

Val is extremely unclear and handwavy in the video. The journalists seem perplexed, one even shrugs in doubt at his attempts to take everyone around the table for granted as "reasonable center-left" voters like himself.
To make sense of it all, you have to look back in history.
In the early years of Charlie Hebdo, the newspaper was definitely anti-clerical and anti-militarist, in the sake of the May 1968 youth protests in France. No doubt that Val, who was 16 at the time of the revolt and later went to become a singer in Paris's bohême cabarets and collaborated with '68 activist artists, was influenced by it. It was probably difficult to escape the libertaire vibes in these areas of the capital at the time anyway, and Charlie still had that aura when Val took over the publication in 1992. More importantly, Val's 25 year long comical duet with Patrick Font was acid-tonged and violently critical of the political, religious, military and police powers that be. In short, you can say that Val indeed used to be libertaire in the anti-conservative sense of the word, the conservative forces of that time being strict morals, religion and the army.
Fast forward 25 years... Things have changed considerably. There is no longer a military service. Churches are slowly emptying. The soixante-huitard generation are now the university teachers, well-to-do politicians, marketing tycoons, media moguls of the day. They are the establishment. Val (as well as a lot of the former Trotskyst, Maoist, anarchist militants) has gradually shifted from a shade of far left to the center left. He's offered a director position at the biggest public radio channel. He has aged and now accepts, willingly or under pressure, to fire humorists even though their politically incorrect jokes are peanuts compared to what he used to sing and what was printed in his former magazine. And then there's the 2015 terrorist slaughter. No wonder your views shift from liberal to more conservative after that.
So yes, you can be both libertaire and center left - at different times of your life. And it's difficult to admit that you're no longer the open-minded beatnik you used to be, especially when you don't realize the definition of open-minded has shifted so much. So you claim to be both at the same time.

"In short, you can say that Val indeed used to be libertaire in the anti-conservative sense of the word, the conservative forces of that time being strict morals, religion and the army." That's also how I think the term "libertaire" must be interpreted in the Charlie Hebdo context (see my own answer), and if that's the case, then maybe "libertaire" and "center-left" are not that uncompatible. Speaking about the 60's vibes, I think at that time, Charlie Hebdo's members were maybe, as you point out, more full-blown "libertaire" (= left anarchists) (in the Guy Debord' fashion)

Agree. To me the question is more "what does it mean to be libertaire in 2024?" What authoritarianism is he fighting? If it is one that almost disappeared by the end of the 20th century, can he even call himself that any more? Also, what does it mean to be center left in 2024? What's left of his leftism? :)

"What authoritarianism is he fighting?" I feel you refer to the fact that the "libertaires" in the 60s were fighting against the authoritarianism of de Gaulle, so "libertaire" would be more like an "anti-(something something of authority") than a political theory. I didn't know we could define it that way, but that seems quite plausible. Otherwise, if "libertaire" means anarchy, then it's not fighting against an authoritarian regime, but for a staless society. Center-left means "social liberalism" in my understanding.

It is possible that by "libertaire", Philippe Val makes consciously or not reference here to the values and style of the journal Charlie Hebdo (he headed for 17 years):

strong irreverence to the political world (from the left to the right)

strongly anti-religious

anti-capitalism


Therefore I think he uses the term "libertaire" to describe:

a level of irreverence (a level of very large freedom of tone) used to criticize some entities considered as holding authority (organized religions, political parties, etc.).

a freedom from the authority of these typical, but yet specific, sources of power (being free to criticize or not follow any political party, etc.)


This careful analysis reveals that Charlie Hebdo "libertaire" values are more those of a journalistic (left-leaning) style than those of a systematic political philosophy (e.g. anarchism; otherwise, they would not vote center-left...).


I always felt a little libertaire all that, but, center-left, when I went to vote you see what I mean"
(original: "je me suis toujours senti un peu libertaire tout ça, mais, centre-gauche, quand j'allais voter quoi"; Philippe Val, [C à vous][3], 2022, 4:35).

I think the quote pretty much summarizes it: this person is libertaire when it comes their beliefs, but they vote center-left (presumably for practical reasons - rather than wasting their vote on a marginal political movement closer in line with their beliefs.)
This is not unlike being a socialist or even communist in the US, but voting for the Democratic party and its rather centrist candidates.
Remark
Note that translator's false friends libertaire and liberal mean in France not the same thing as libertarian and liberal in the US.

"This is not unlike being a socialist or even communist" but in my knowledge, there is a trend in communism/reformism which is not revolutionary, but plays the rules of democracy (to turn the state into a socialist state, through reforms, elections, votes, etc.) But this is not, IMU, the case of anarchy (libertaire)!

@Starckman this is not what is meant in this case. In 2016 it was considered a real risk that Sanders' supporters would not vote for Hillary... although most of them did in the end. As for the rest: terms communism/socialism are used very loosely - Marxism is not compatible with liberal democracy (according to Marx and his followers), whereas socialism is often confused with social democracy. XIX-th century German SPD indeed engaged in a debate about whether socialism can be achieved via democratic means, but they fully abandoned Marxism somewhere in 1970s.

Sorry, a typo "there is a trend in communism/socialism". "whereas socialism is often confused with social democracy". As I understand it, socialism has two meanings, 1) referring to the large spectrum of ideologies which advocate for the socialization of the means of production (so encompasses Marxist communism, left anarchism, social-democracy, etc.) 2) referring to indeed the "reformist" current of socialism (playing the rules of liberal democracy), which has emerged in Germany and in France, taking the term "socialism", and therefore turning this term as meaning indeed "social democracy"

"In 2016 it was considered a real risk that Sanders' supporters would not vote for Hillary..." Normally, a Marxist communist (as you pointed out) is a revolutionary, so he should not vote (I know there are some debates about that, but at the very least he should not vote for a non-communist, but only for a communist.) Otherwise, there is too much self-contradiction. Centrists can go voting, and then choose between a center-left or a center-right

@Starckman I have covered some of the debate about socialism vs. social democracy in this answer. Social democracy as exists in western Europe does not imply socialization of the means of production, but only redistribution of wealth - it is inherently capitalistic. On the other hand, XIX-th century German socialists actually wanted to abolish capitalism by parliamentary means - as you said in your comment.

It's always difficult to argue with stereotypes. I mean, I frequently hear people ask how it's possible to be Christian (devoted to Christ's model of love and acceptance) and xenophobic (hateful and fearful of difference), but Christian Nationalism is all the rage these days. The truth is that un-philosophical people are good at compartmentalizing — believing and behaving one way in some contexts, while believing and behaving differently in different contexts — and there's no rationalizing it because it's explicitly un-philosophical.
What Val likely means is that he'd prefer it if no one interfered with him at all, ever (hence libertaire), but recognizes that other people (bad, stupid people; or at least people unlike him) need to be controlled and moderated by the state, and so he wants to vote for leaders and laws that will do that to them (but not to him). Typical Fundamental Attribution Error position that most people in the world are subject to. C'est la vie!
